# Accessing Column Aliases in R

Tags: r, vector, alias

I have a list of column aliases I am creating based on a dataframe.

```
column_aliases <- c("colA" = "Column A", "colB" = "Column B", "colC" = "Column C")
```

I know that the `names()` function can be used to access `"colA"`, `"colB"`, and `"colC"`; however, is there a good function to access `"Column A"`, `"Column B"`, and `"Column C"`? I am having trouble finding one.

Thank you!

Comment: Simply print `column_aliases`? Like `column_aliases[2]` returns `"Column B"`.

Comment: I'd like to have a list of all the column aliases, like how the `names()` function returns a list of all the original names @MartinGal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your response to Martin Gal's comment maybe you mean something like `unname(column_aliases)`?

```
unname(column_aliases)
[1] "Column A" "Column B" "Column C"
```

Answer (score 3):

Some more approaches -

1. `as.vector`

```
as.vector(column_aliases)
#[1] "Column A" "Column B" "Column C"
```

2. `c()`

```
c(column_aliases, use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "Column A" "Column B" "Column C"
```

3. `c(t())`

```
c(t(column_aliases))
#[1] "Column A" "Column B" "Column C"
```

Comment: Great answer. I really like 2. because it is quite clear what you are doing and why.
1. is ok but if glanced over it I would probably think there is some "bigger" transformation happening. 3. is probably gonna confuse me quite a bit when I read the code.